# how to poll message from SQS using celery worker, the message is in JSON format and worker not able to decode the format

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, polling, worker

how to poll message from SQS using celery worker, the message is in JSON format and worker not able to decode the format

Note: These messages are not sent into SQS using celery beat, This queue is subscribed from SNS

my celery worker command is: 
celery worker -A status_handling -l info -Q es_status_test

```
Msg in Queue:

{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "f7e40fd9-8f92-59c5-afd9-5a1847aaae57",
  "TopicArn" : "***",
  "Message" : "{\"SESResponseStatusCode\": 200, \"Status\": \"Delivered\", \"Message\": \"Email sent successfully.\", \"MessageId\": \"a59e85a2-8b7a-4b49-9354-0a7a4170b0c0\", \"Uuid\": null}",
  "Timestamp" : "2019-08-05T06:00:24.943Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "pass",
  "SigningCertURL" : "pass",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "pass"
}
```

Error is coming:

```
[2019-08-04 23:00:25,116: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 596, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 91, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 362, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 111, in on_readable
    return self._on_event(fd, _pycurl.CSELECT_IN)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 124, in _on_event
    self._process_pending_requests()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 130, in _process_pending_requests
    self._process(curl)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/http/curl.py", line 178, in _process
    buffer=buffer, effective_url=effective_url, error=error,
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 177, in __call__
    svpending(*ca, **ck)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 167, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 100, in _transback
    return callback(ret)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 167, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 100, in _transback
    return callback(ret)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self.throw()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 167, in __call__
    retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 98, in _transback
    callback.throw()
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 96, in _transback
    ret = filter_(*args + (ret,), **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 370, in _on_messages_ready
    msg_parsed = self._message_to_python(msg, qname, queue)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/SQS.py", line 236, in _message_to_python
    payload = loads(bytes_to_str(body))
  File "/home/vagrant/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 94, in loads
    return stdjson.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQS support in Celery is only intended as a transport mechanism for Celery-specific messages. You cannot use Celery to consume arbitrary SQS messages.

Instead, I'd suggest writing a custom Django management command in which you poll your SQS queue using the boto3 library.